# How to change GitHub repository in IDEA intelliJ

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I have a project in intelliJ that's synchronized with a GitHub repository and I want to change it to another repository (same account).

To clarify: I have project A on repository R1. I have another repository R2.

I want to push the project A to repository R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot edit Git remotes from within IntelliJ. There is a feature request to add this at [IDEA-87099](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87099), or at least to be able to add remotes. Currently you have to use the commandline or any other git client to manage remotes of a repository. If the remote is added though, you can push, pull, diff etc. with IntelliJ.

You can of course also simply edit `.git/config` from within IntelliJ to add the remote configuration without the need to execute any further commandline or GUI tool.

Comment: Thanks, but, how do I do that in Windows? Should I just open Git Bash in the directory and type the command?

Comment: Yes, you can. Or you install TortoiseGit or any other Windows Git UI frontend you like. But usually I juse command-line git for most stuff.

Comment: I added another way to the answer. Btw. please accept and eventually upvote if the answer is sufficient for you.